# Resouce in .resx file not visible to MVC code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resx

I have a solution with two projects. One is called Resources and is a collection of resource .resx files for localization. The other is an MVC 5 project that has Resources as a reference. I define a new resource in the .resx file called EmailAddress and sure enough it is in  Resource.Designer,cs:

```
 internal static string EmailAddress {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("EmailAddress", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
```

However, when I try to refernce in my Model class it says it doesn't exist:

```
[Display(Name = "EmailAddress", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailRequired")]
        [RegularExpression(".+@.+\\..+", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
                                         ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailInvalid")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Also, if I try to do this a Razor View, it doesn't show up in the Intellisense:

```
@Resources.Resources.
```

What is going on? I should also state that the resource file was originally taken from a sample project and the resources that were in it show up but any I add don't (but its the designer cs file).

Comment: Make sure your project has a reference to your resources project. Also in your view you will need to add the @using statement followed by your projectnamespace

Comment: I have both and it still does not find any that I add. The "original set" is there. I get this error on running with the model the way shown above "Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.  Type 'Resources.Resources' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name 'EmailAddress'."

Comment: What is the Build Action (under file properties when you select the .resx file) of your resources vs the files from the original sample?

Comment: Also, when editing your .resx file, is the Access Modifier set to Public or Internal?

Comment: They are all set to Internal. I don't see how to change this. The ones that work all internal too.

Comment: I changed them all to public and got the same error

Comment: To start with, the .resx will need the [Access Modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) set to Public to be seen outside the assembly. Not sure why that wouldn't fix it in your case. Can you verify that the properties in the Designer file were updated accordingly? Is your reference from MVC to Resource set to the project, or to a snapshot DLL somewhere?

Comment: Yes, they are now set to Public. The reference is set to a class library project (DLL). I am still getting "Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.  Type 'Resources.Resources' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name 'EmailAddress'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59415/discussion-between-mike-guthrie-and-user2471435).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, in my case it was solved by doing 2 things to those resource files:

- Set the custom Tool to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator.
- Set the build action to "Embedded Resource".
- Additionally added the reference in the web.config for the views to the resources in the namespaces section.

After that, it was solved so I was able to call it as "`@Resources.Resources.EmailAddress`"